# nagios - memory configuration

Tags: memory, nagios

I am trying to configure nagios to perform memory check on a ubuntu server. I already have the basic configuration but when a try to start nagios, the following error message is displayed:

**Service check command 'check_mem' specified in service 'Current Memory Usage' for host 'xxxx' not defined anywhere!**

Besides commands.cfg, is there any possible place to define the command to be executed?

Thanks in advance,
Best regards!

Comment: commands.cfg is probably the best place to define check_mem, yes.  was that what you wanted to know, or have i misunderstood the question?

Comment: The current configuration is based on an already existing one and I know for sure, that the command definition for memory checking is not placed on commands.cfg.

Comment: Yes, that's what NAGIOS is telling you: it's not defined *anywhere*.  You need to define it.  commands.cfg would be a good place to do that.  Is that what you were asking?

Comment: I am asking if there is other possible file to place the command definition. As I said, I have a running configuration where the check_mem definitions is not placed on the file commands.cfg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rui:

ok, that's much clearer.  The answer is that NAGIOS can take any valid configuration statement in any of its configuration files, and there can be an unlimited number of these.  I have a NAGIOS server with 136 config files; any of those could contain a command definition.

So if you have a running configuration that has it defined somewhere, but not in commands.cfg, then the bad news is it could be in any of its config files, and  these can be anywhere.

If I wanted to find it, I'd look in nagios.cfg to see what directories the config files live in, then automate the process of finding it, perhaps with

```
find /config/directory1 /config/directory2 /you-get-the-idea  -type f -exec grep check_mem {} /dev/null \;
```

and see what matches that finds.

Comment: Here is the result of the command execution for the /etc/nagios3/conf.d directory: /etc/nagios3/conf.d/localhost.cfg:        check_command check_mem!7!3. Any more suggestions for a file/directory where the check_mem command may be located?

Comment: Rui, start with nagios.cfg, as I advised.  That file likely lists all the other config files, or the directories where they live.  You *are* running this on the server that has check_mem correctly set up, aren't you?

Comment: Thanks to you search suggestion, I had finally found the check_mem command definition. I executed the command find /etc/ -type f -exec grep check_mem {} /dev/null \; and the output was the directory and file were it was defined: /etc/nagios-plugins/config/memory.cfg. Thanks all for the help!

Comment: Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 0):

most probably you want to use [nagios nrpe server](https://help.ubuntu.com/9.10/serverguide/C/nagios.html) on monitored machine and define what plugin should execute this check.

btw maybe you should rather check swap usage?

Comment: As I said on a previous comment, there is a running configuration on other servers and they are not using the nrpe server. As rather checking the swap usage, it is a good question. I don't know for sure if the perl script used for the memory check is "oriented" for the swap usage or not.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a decent script for checking memory so I wrote the following. I use it with nrpe as suggested above.

Service definition on the server in the host config:

> ```
> define service {
>        use                     generic-service
>        host_name               <hostname>
>        service_description     Memory Usage
>        check_command           check_nrpe_1arg!check_memory
> }
> ```

This needs to be defined in /etc/nagios/nrpe.cfg on the client, amended for the values you want to check for:

```
command[check_memory]=/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_memory.sh -w 85 -c 90
```

Example output:

```
#:~$ ./check_memory.sh -w 80 -c 90
Memory OK. 44% used.


#:~$ ./check_memory.sh -w 40 -c 50
Memory WARNING. 44% used.
```

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Script to check memory usage on Linux. Ignores memory used by disk cache. 
#
# Requires the bc command
#
print_help() {
    echo "Usage:"
    echo "[-w] Warning level as a percentage" 
    echo "[-c] Critical level as a percentage" 
    exit 0
}

while test -n "$1"; do
    case "$1" in
        --help|-h)
            print_help
            exit 0
            ;;
        -w)
            warn_level=$2
            shift
            ;;
        -c)
            critical_level=$2
            shift
            ;;
        *)
            echo "Unknown Argument: $1"
            print_help
            exit 3
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done

if [ "$warn_level" == "" ]; then
    echo "No Warning Level Specified"
    print_help
    exit 3;
fi

if [ "$critical_level" == "" ]; then
    echo "No Critical Level Specified"
    print_help
    exit 3;
fi


free=`free -m | grep "buffers/cache" | awk '{print $4}'`
used=` free -m | grep "buffers/cache" | awk '{print $3}'`

total=$(($free+$used))

result=$(echo "$used / $total * 100" |bc -l|cut -c -2)

if [ "$result" -lt "$warn_level" ]; then
    echo "Memory OK. $result% used."
    exit 0;
elif [ "$result" -ge "$warn_level" ] && [ "$result" -le "$critical_level" ]; then
    echo "Memory WARNING. $result% used."
    exit 1;
elif [ "$result" -gt "$critical_level" ]; then
    echo "Memory CRITICAL. $result% used."
    exit 2;
fi
```

Comment: Honestly, I don't quite understand the memory analysis which is performed by your script? Is it more oriented to get the free swap?

Comment: It gets the amount of free memory, without including buffers/cache. It doesn't include any swap. You can compare the output of the script with gnome-system-monitor.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is nagios server can't find `check_nrpe_1arg`'s define. 
There are somewhere else you can define commands, e.g nagios-plugins

Here, I solve the problem by define command in plugins

```
deploy@code:/etc/nagios-plugins/config$ pwd
/etc/nagios-plugins/config
deploy@code:/etc/nagios-plugins/config$ cat check_nrpe.cfg 
# this command runs a program $ARG1$ with arguments $ARG2$
define command {
    command_name    check_nrpe
    command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$ -a                 $ARG2$
}


# this command runs a program $ARG1$ with no arguments
define command {
    command_name    check_nrpe_1arg
    command_line    /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe -H $HOSTADDRESS$ -c $ARG1$
}
```

To use `check_nrpe` or `check_nrpe_1arg`, you must make sure `/usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_nrpe` exist. In debian system, you can install package `nagios-nrpe-plugins` on the nagios server.